# How to protect fields from mass assignment in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mass-assignment

A Mongoose model, Thing, has two fields, only one of which (safe) should be settable through [mass assignment](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment):

```
var db = require('mongoose');

var schema = new db.Schema({
  safe:   { type: String }, // settable through mass assignment
  unsafe: { type: String }  // not settable through mass assignment
});

db.model('Thing', schema);
```

A controller sets up Thing by passing parameters:

```
exports.create = function(req, res) {
  var thing = new Thing(req.body);

  // more...
};
```

An attacker could try to set thing.unsafe by making a JSON POST request in which unsafe is set. This should be prevented.

It would be great if something like the Rails attr_accessible functionality were available for Mongoose. I did find [mongoose-mass-assign](https://github.com/bhelx/mongoose-mass-assignment), but this is nothing like what I'm looking for. For one thing, mongoose-mass-assign apparently requires the use of a new API (two massAssign functions). I want mass assignment protection for any native Mongoose model function to which params hashes are passed, for example, the Thing constructor and the Thing.create function.

How can I get mass assignment protection for Mongoose models? If not available, how do Mongoose users currently protect against this vulnerability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facepalm:

```
var thing = new Thing(req.body);
```

Slightly saner:

```
var okFields = {};
okFields.safe = req.body.safe
var thing = new Thing(okFields);
//Also helpful for longer whitelists from underscore: _.pick(req.body, "safe");
//Also feel free to add some, y'know, data validation either here or in mongoose
```

Just don't do that. Rails has taught you a terrible antipattern. But to answer your question, AFAIK mongoose nor mongodb has no mechanism to enforce anything analogous to rails's attr_accessible or any concept of tainted variables.

Comment: Why 'antipattern' and 'Facepalm'? Makes sense given no support for whitelisting mechanism like attr_accessible. It sounds like you're saying there is no whitelist, so don't do mass assignment, which seems, well, obvious and the point of the question. FWIW, validation was omitted to keep the example focused on the mass assignment problem.

Comment: The notion that you can just take a raw block of data from an untrusted client and shove it into your database is simply false. You cannot do this in any realistic application. You have data validations to run and authorizations to check. Secure production code simply never looks like this. It's a silly hack to get demo blog applications running in 100 lines of code. Nothing more.

Comment: Thanks for the perspective. I've used the approach you outlined and it works fine.

Comment: With Mongoose's `strict` mode (default for version 3+), fields not in the schema won't get saved to the db. Thus, you could use `_.omit` or otherwise blacklist fields and be pretty safe. Whitelisting is less prone to developer error than blacklisting though.